# form not getting submitted through ajax

Tags: php, ajax, validation

Here the form get submitted when all the validation is correct.But for radio button and select button the validation is not getting correctly and i want only few fields to be validated but the form is getting submitted only when validation is given to all the fields...
This is my  page...

```
<form id="contact" name="contact" class="form-horizontal"  method="POST" action="">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">NAME</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" data-rule-required="true" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">AGE</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="age" id="age">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">GENDER</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio"  name="gender" id="inlineRadio1" value="male" class="required">
              Male </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" name="gender" id="inlineRadio2" value="female">
              Female </label>
          </div>
       </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">OCCUPATION</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text"   class="form-control" name="occupation" id="occupation">
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">AREA</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <select class="form-control required"  name="area">
              <option selected="selected"   value="" >Please Choose</option>
              <option value="A.Naranapura">A.Naranapura</option>
              <option value="Abshot Layout"> Abshot Layout</option>
              <option value="Adugodi"> Adugodi</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-8">
            <button id="send" class="btn btn-default fran">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </form>
```

This is my ajax..

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       function validateEmail(email) { 
          var reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
          return reg.test(email);
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {


          $("#contact").submit(function() { return false; });


          $("#send").on("click", function(){
            var emailval  = $("#email").val();
            var ageval    = $("#age").val();
            var nameval    = $("#name").val();
            var numval    = $("#contact-number").val();
            var genval    = $("#gender").val();
            var occuval    = $("#occupation").val();

            var areaval    = $("#area").val();

            var mailvalid = validateEmail(emailval);
            var namelen=nameval.length;
            var genlen=genval.length;
            var occculen=occupationval.length;
            var addresslen=addressval.length;
            var numlen=numval.length;

            var arealen=areaval.length;



            if(mailvalid == false) {
              $("#email").addClass("error");
            }
            else if(mailvalid == true){
              $("#email").removeClass("error");
            }
            if(namelen < 1) {
              $("#name").addClass("error");
            }
            else if(namelen >= 1){
              $("#name").removeClass("error");
            }
            if(genlen < 1) {
              $("#gender").addClass("error");
            }
            else if(genlen >= 1){
              $("#gender").removeClass("error");
            }
            if(addresslen < 1) {
              $("#address").addClass("error");
            }
            else if(addresslen >= 1){
              $("#address").removeClass("error");
            }

            if(occulen < 1) {
              $("#occupation").addClass("error");
            }
            else if(occulen >= 1){
              $("#occupation").removeClass("error");
            }
            if(numlen < 1) {
              $("#contact-number").addClass("error");
            }
            else if(numlen >= 1){
              $("#contact-number").removeClass("error");
            }

            if(arealen < 1) {
              $("#area").addClass("error");
            }
            else if(arealen >= 1){
              $("#area").removeClass("error");
            }


   if(mailvalid == true && namelen >=1 && genlen >= 1 && addresslen >= 1 && occulen >= 1 && numlen >= 1 && arealen >= 1 ) {
    // if both validate we attempt to send the e-mail
    // first we hide the submit btn so the user doesnt click twice
    $("#send").replaceWith("<em>sending...</em>");

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'sendfranchiseemessage.php',
      data: $("#contact").serialize(),

      success: function(data) {

        if(data == "true") {
         alert();
         $("#contact").fadeOut("fast", function(){
          $(this).before("<p><strong><h1>Success! Your feedback has been sent, thanks :)</h1></strong></p>");
          setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
        });
       }
     }
   });
  }
});
        });
      </script>
```

Comment: Uncomment line /*var genlen=genval.length;*/

Comment: Too many issues in your code. E.g: address field not there in form. genlen field is in comment. radio button validation not work using length you need to use checked or not and same for select dropdown check for option value is !=0, etc...

Comment: sorry..now see my code

Comment: Are you checking your code error? still too much error coming as i am checking it in my system. Please correct the code and then tell us your real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the path for the php that handles the ajax if it is correct. also, see below.

```
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'sendfranchiseemessage.php',
  data: $("#contact").serialize(),

  success: function(data) {
    alert( data );
    if(data == "true") {
     alert();
     $("#contact").fadeOut("fast", function(){
      $(this).before("<p><strong><h1>Success! Your feedback has been sent, thanks :)</h1></strong></p>");
      setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
    });
   }
 }
```

See if it does alert the data when you click submit on the form.

Comment: its getting alerted..but my problem is for radio button and select button how can i give validation like this                                                    if(namelen < 1)  {
              $("#name").addClass("error");
            }
            else if(namelen >= 1){
              $("#name").removeClass("error");
            }

Comment: the above validation is for text field and giving validation by comparing with the length of that field

Comment: Use this to validate you radion button.

if($('input:radio[name=priority]').is(':checked')){
 // do something
}

Comment: Also, when you validate your text field you can use this.

if( name != '' ){ do something }

Comment: Also, you can use this to fetch all your form data.

data: $("#contact").serializeArray()

Then you do a loop to check the fields if empty and valid.